# Hide html h3 links via custom CSS in Joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla

I wanted to hide that in Joomla using the custom CSS

This is the link to my site:
http://guamlfp.org/test

I am trying to remove the title of the articles "About" and "Vision"

I need the CSS code to hide the following HTML:

```html
<a href="/component/content/article/9-aboutlfp/6-aboutlfp?Itemid=101" itemprop="url">About</a>

<h3><a href="/component/content/article/11-vision/7-vision?Itemid=101" itemprop="url">Vision</a></h3>
```

Comment: so in your site you just want to hide the heading of h3 size or you want to remove the content also

Comment: you need hide top of two links or red color title

Comment: if we add the css like h3{display: none;}, it will be affected to every h3 which is not a good way.  Can you explain the scenario. Also do you have code level control in joomla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this css in your css

**css**

```
.sppb-article-info-wrap h3{
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: it didn't worked. i also tested it at jsfiddle.net. it didn't remove the code.

Comment: please share correct html code and .. which part want to you hide? pls explain

Comment: please kindly check my website: http://guamlfp.org/test i am trying to remove "About" and "Vision" red titles.

Comment: pls try above css code.. i modifyed

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of different ways to hide it. you can do it directly to the html or you can use css.

## 1. Using HTML

```
<h3 style="display: none;" >
    <a href="/component/content/article/11-vision/7-vision?Itemid=101" itemprop="url">Vision</a>
</h3>
```

## 2. Using CSS

### HTML Code

```
<h3 class="header--vision" >
    <a href="/component/content/article/11-vision/7-vision?Itemid=101" itemprop="url">Vision</a>
</h3>
```

### CSS Code

```
.header--vision {
    display: none;
}
```